# Adding new items in a listview via ajax submit

Tags: java, ajax, listview, wicket

I'm tring to create a search based on date.
I've tried so many different way to repaint a Ajax table with listview. 
the listview works fine while I use is loading  the page -- 
but when Try to add it to ajaxsubmit buttun - 
I have the markup created for example -18 new row is created - but data is not there. 
So the question is how do I add data in the ajax enabled listview tags?

===================

```
final ListView logTableListView = new ListView<SyslogParsed>("List"){

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<SyslogParsed> item) {
                //SyslogParsed sp = item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("col1"));
                item.add(new Label("col2" ));
                item.add(new Label("col3") );
                item.add(new Label("col4" ));

            }


        };    


    final PropertyModel<List<SyslogParsed>> sysLogPropertyModel =  new     PropertyModel<List<SyslogParsed>>(this, "Dao.findAll");


    wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    wmc.add(logTableListView);
    add(wmc);

    logTableListView.setReuseItems(true);


    sysLogSearchForm.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("submit"){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

            List<?> allLog =  syslogParsedDao.findAll();

            logTableListView.setList(allLog);               logTableListView.modelChanged();


            target.add(wmc);
        }


    });
```

===============

```
 <table class="sortable" wicket:id="listContainer">
               <tr>
                 <th> col 1</th>
                 <th> col2</th>
                 <th>col 3 </th>
                 <th> col 4</th>
               </tr>
               <tr wicket:id="List">
                 <td  wicket:id="col1" > </td>
                 <td wicket:id="col2"> </td> 
                 <td wicket:id="col3"> </td> 
                 <td wicket:id="col4"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </wicket:extend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are actually setting the lists model. try to instantiate the propertymodel first, then construct the listview like

```
new ListView<SyslogParsed>("List", sysLogPropertyModel )
```

The propertymodel will then call

`this.getDAO().getFindAll()` in this instance. Therefore it looks like you data will never be found, moreover the listview does not have any modelobject and will not notify any changes.

You can try using an AbstractReadonlyModel like

```
new ListView<SyslogParsed>("List", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<SyslogParsed>() {
          public SyslogParsed getObject() {
                  getSyslogparsedao().findAll();
          }
});
```

and adding the listviews container to the ajaxrequesttarget in your submit method. Every time you are rerender the view, the models getObject will be called and the listview is getting the refreshed data.

Comment: OK -  Thanks for answering so fast. 
How do I add  Label markup like this ->  item.add(new Label("col1"));

I want the initial table to be empty. 
when I click it will add the table via a ajax submit.

Comment: Thanks a lot  - you are great :) 

its working after too much wasted times :)

Comment: osdamv described how to attach your daos values to the lable in your listview. if your question is anwered, rate and mark the thread as anwered please :)

Answer (score 2):

first check your ListView have a model assigned(i think yes because display 18 rows..) then in your populateItem use  PropertyModel, for example

```
protected void populateItem(ListItem<SyslogParsed> item) {
  SyslogParsed sp = item.getModelObject();
  item.add(new Label("col1",new PropertyModel<SyslogParsed>(sp, "blabla1")));
  item.add(new Label("col2",new PropertyModel<SyslogParsed>(sp, "blabla2") ));
  item.add(new Label("col3",new PropertyModel<SyslogParsed>(sp, "blabla3")) );
  item.add(new Label("col4",new PropertyModel<SyslogParsed>(sp, "blabla4") ));
}
```

also you could use CompoundPropertyModel

Comment: then in the ajaxsubmit - how do I add new item to the listview ?

Comment: you just change the model, and then you repaint the container of the listview, wicket(dont allow repaint a fragment of a repeater), target.add(containerOfList);

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- wicket(dont allow repaint a fragment of a repeater)

I figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough repo to vote your answer - both of the answer actually solve my problem == Here what I've done --

## added a dummy model first

```
     AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<LogParsed>> emptyListModel = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<LogParsed>>(){ 
        @Override public List<logParsed> getObject() { 
     List<logParsed> emptyList = new ArrayList<LogParsed>(); 
        LogParsed sp = new LogParsed(); 

        emptyList.add(sp); return emptyList; 
} };
=====


    final  AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<LogParsed>> listModel =  new  AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<v>>()
        {

            @Override
            public List<LogParsed> getObject() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return LogParsed.findAll();
            }
        };   


      final ListView<logParsed> logTableListView = new ListView<logParsed>("logList",emptyListModel ){

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<logParsed> item) {
                logParsed sp = item.getModelObject();

                item.add(new Label("sdo somthing"," "+ sp.getdosomthing() ));

            }


        };    

        //wmc.setVisible(false); 
        wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        wmc.add(logTableListView);
        add(wmc);

        logTableListView.setList(new ArrayList<logParsed>());
        //logTableListView.setReuseItems(true);

        AjaxSubmitLink aj =  new AjaxSubmitLink("submit"){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

                logTableListView.setDefaultModel(listModel );
                logTableListView.modelChanged();
                target.add(wmc);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget arg0, Form<?> arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    };
        logSearchForm.add(aj);

    return logSearchForm;

}
====
```

The trick is this when you create list view - you have to define how repeating item will be created - 
so when you change you model in ajaxsubmit - the repeating element can follow the previous pattern.

Hope someone will find this answer useful